# Dell pc. System halted with Ubuntu

Tags: dell

Good day dear friends!

I have PC dell Precision 3650 Tower

It worked quite good

After update Ubuntu i restart system and try to join. I do it via login and password. And after moment when i pressed enter I see only black screen.

System halted

Only one way  join via ctrl alt f3

After I see terminal. Where I put login and password , and I see home directory

It is look like gnome not working.

I use Ubuntu with cancer. 23 10.

Please help

Comment: sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target

Comment: unfortunalley - it is not working.

Comment: After long effort i got result. i updated BIOS and not it is work good